# Different shapes at the time of assignment and declaration of typescript

Tags: typescript

I wonder why.

When I declared, it doesn't  assignment.

```
...
let c:A = {a: "A", b: "B"}; // Error
...
```

But Why does it OK when assignment statement?

```
...
a = b; // OK
...
```

All Code

```
type A = { a : string }
type B = { a : string, b : string }

let a:A = {a: 'a'};
let b:B = {a: "A", b: "B"}; 
a = b; // OK

let c:A = {a: "A", b: "B"};  // Error
```

Comment: I can't understand what you mean by "execute" here.  But [excess property checking](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-6.html#stricter-object-literal-assignment-checks) only applies to *object literals* being directly assigned to a type with fewer properties.  The line `a = b` is not assigning an object literal at all, so no excess property checks happen.

Comment: @jcalz Thank you. 
The question has been resolved. I "execute" mean "a = b;". What do you say?

Comment: I would call `a = b` an *assignment statement*, but I still don't quite understand the meaning of "When I declared, it doesn't executed. Why does it execute when allocating?" even if I replace "execute" with "assign".  This is probably a language barrier.  It's okay though because the example code is clear.

Comment: Thank you very much.
It's a very helpful answer for me.